# Occasional delays in response from azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I maintain an azure cloud service. It is set to auto-scale based on load. To monitor the health of this service I have another service which pings this service every 2 minutes. The usual response time from this service is around 100ms.

Once or twice a week I see that the service does not respond. It is not really a worry for me - because it happens quite infrequently. I still am trying to figure out what could be causing the service to not respond. I do not think the problem is with the pinging service - I don't see any of the other services (not on azure, but on other servers) that it pings having any issues.

What could be causing these occasional delays. Any other azure service owners seeing such delays ?

Comment: How long do unresponsive times last?  Is it just some random requests tha times out or is it happening for some continous amount of time?  how many servers are you running? how busy is your site?

Comment: As Igore was alluding to, you don't provide nearly enough information for anybody to provide a solution.  To answer your specific question, no, this is not a normal behavior for Azure services which points to something specific within your application.  Forget the fact that your site is in Azure - how would you troubleshoot on-prem?  IIS logs, perf counters, application logging, SQL perf stats, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Having quite similar problems. But I use Applications Inside, so I have some statistics. For example that reponse time increases together with SQL azure access time and CPU usage. My average response time according to Applications Inside is about 600ms and average RPS is about 0,6. During these problems RPS usually higher than avarage - up to 1.5, but average response time grows up to 1min! (During the day my RPS can grow up to 3 or even higher without any reponse time growth). As I have 1min sql connection timeout and I have drammatical growth of total SQL azure access time during this periods I can assume that problem happens bacause of SQL Azure.  This also happens once a day or two, for about 10-15 minutes max and my ping service also always reports that service doesn't respond. 
So my advice here - install Application Insights to analyze what happens dusring these response delays. It would be great if you share your results here.

P.S. I also use autoscale based on load. Though it doesn't really help in these concrete situations.